# Increase value in new cell if number in cell A changes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im working with an excel sheet that has a number of duplicate values. I want a value in a new cell to increase by 1 every time the value in cell A changes.
My excel sheet currently looks something like this:

```
ID   New Number
4
5
6
7
7
7
8
8
9
```

How can I set the New Number column to start at number 2317 and then increase that value by 1 every time Column A's number changes?

Comment: please try to use array formula with =IF(B2:B1000<>"",ROW(B2:B1000)-ROW(B2)+1,"")

Comment: It might just be a very basic example by your end, but in `B2` put: `=2313+A2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B2`, put `2317`.

In `B3`, put `=IF(A3<>A2,B2+1,B2)` and drag down.

[image]

<sub>Note that this can be simplified to `=B2+(A3<>A2)`</sub>